# how to update progress of the progress bar to show the progress of copying a file

Tags: file, javafx, progress-bar, file-transfer

I want a progress bar to indicate files being copied
how to update the progress bar to show the progress of copying a file by combining below lines of code??

here's my code for progressbar.

```
@FXML
private void startbtnaction(ActionEvent event) {
    startbtn.setDisable(true);
    progressbar.setProgress(0);
    txt.setText("");
    cancelbtn.setDisable(false);
    copyworker = createWorker(numFiles);

    progressbar.progressProperty().unbind();
    progressbar.progressProperty().bind(copyworker.progressProperty());
    progressindicator.progressProperty().unbind();
    progressindicator.progressProperty().bind(copyworker.progressProperty());

         copyworker.messageProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>(){

                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
                    txt.setText(newValue+"\n");
                }  
            });
        new Thread(copyworker).start();

}
 private Task createWorker(int numFiles) {
   return new Task(){

       @Override
       protected Object call() throws Exception {
           for (int i = 0; i < numFiles; i++) {
               long elapsedtime=System.currentTimeMillis();
               copyFile("somefile", "some dest file");
               elapsedtime=System.currentTimeMillis()-elapsedtime;
               String status=elapsedtime+"milliseconds";

               updateMessage(status);
               updateProgress(i+1, numFiles);

           }
           return true;

       }

   };
}

 public  void copyFile(String src,String dest)throws InterruptedException{
     Random rnd=new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    long millis=rnd.nextInt(1000);
    Thread.sleep(millis);

 }
```

/// ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

here's my code for file copying..

```
InputStream istream = RemoteInputStreamClient.wrap(sendappcontent);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(istream);

    //downloaded file...
    File file = new File("D:\\SERVER\\Temp\\" + contentfile.getName());//server saving point

    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }

    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    FileChannel channel = fileOutputStream.getChannel();


    byte b[] = new byte[1024];
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (bis.available() > 0) {
        bis.read(b);
        System.out.println("B");
        System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000);
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(b);
        channel.write(buffer);
    }

    bis.close();
    fileOutputStream.flush();
    channel.close();
    fileOutputStream.close();

    System.out.println("done");
```

Comment: So what is the question...?

Comment: how to update the progress bar to show the progress of copying a file.??

Comment: It looks like your code should do that. Please edit your question and explain what happens and how it differs from what you want.

Comment: I want a progress bar to indicate files being copied
how to update the progress bar to show the progress of copying a file by combining below lines of code??

Comment: Your are using `Task#updateProgress` right. You know how many files to copy and after each file is copied, you count one up. So the _progressbar_ and _progressindicator_ get updated correctly, becouse their _progressProperty_ are bind to the _progressProperty_ of the Task. Maybe you want to do that finer grained, so the progress have to get updated while the file is copied. If so, you have to determine the total size of the file to copy and update after each `bis.read(b)` (it returns the number of successfully read bytes.

Comment: does your progress-view update the status? because in the code above everything is ok.